# mapping functions in solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm wondering if it's possible to map functions in a map in solidity, something like:

```
mapping (uint256=> function) function_map;
f(){
    do something;
}
function_map[1] = f;
```

Answer (score 5):

While you can't store the function as a type, you can store the `bytes4` representation and then invoke through `call()`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Test {
    uint public _val;

    mapping(uint => bytes4) _methodToInvoke;

    function Test() public {
        _methodToInvoke[1] = bytes4(keccak256("incrementBy1()"));
        _methodToInvoke[2] = bytes4(keccak256("incrementBy2()"));
    }

    function incrementBy1() public {
        _val++;
    }

    function incrementBy2() public {
        _val += 2;
    }

    function invoke(uint idx) public returns (bool) {
        return this.call(_methodToInvoke[idx]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the ethereum solidity documentation: 
[Mapping in ethereum solidity](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings)

> Mappings are only allowed for state variables (or as storage reference types in internal functions).

So the answer is no. (so far)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, mapping Solidity is looked like a `hasMap` in the JAVA I mean like a `key-value`. So you can read more details on this link.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings

This example for mapping

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract TodoList {
  struct Todo {
    bytes32 id;
    string title;
    string description;
    bool mark;
  }

  mapping(address => Todo[]) todoLookups;

  event Add(address from, bytes32 _id);
  event Remove(address from, bytes32 _id);
  event Update(address from, bytes32 _id);

  function add(string memory _title, string memory _description) public {
    bytes32 id = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, todoLookups[msg.sender].length + 1));
    todoLookups[msg.sender].push(Todo(id, _title, _description, false));
    emit Add(msg.sender, id);
  }

  function update(
    bytes32 _id,
    string memory _title,
    string memory _description
  ) public returns (bool) {
    uint256 index = findIndexById(_id);
    Todo memory oldTodo = todoLookups[msg.sender][index];
    todoLookups[msg.sender][index] = Todo(_id, _title, _description, oldTodo.mark);
    emit Update(msg.sender, _id);
    return true;
  }

  function remove(bytes32 _id) public returns (bool) {
    uint256 index = findIndexById(_id);
    todoLookups[msg.sender][index] = todoLookups[msg.sender][todoLookups[msg.sender].length - 1];
    todoLookups[msg.sender].pop();
    emit Remove(msg.sender, _id);
    return true;
  }

  function setMark(bytes32 _id, bool _mark) public returns (bool) {
    uint256 index = findIndexById(_id);
    todoLookups[msg.sender][index].mark = _mark;
    return true;
  }

  function get(bytes32 _id) public view returns (Todo memory item) {
    uint256 index = findIndexById(_id);
    item = todoLookups[msg.sender][index];
  }

  function getAll() public view returns (Todo[] memory items) {
    items = todoLookups[msg.sender];
  }

  function findIndexById(bytes32 _id) internal view returns (uint256) {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < todoLookups[msg.sender].length; i++) {
      if (todoLookups[msg.sender][i].id == _id) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    revert("not found item by this id");
  }
}
```